# Using Reflection to get Stored Procedure name from Entity Data Model.

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, reflection, stored-procedures

Consider I have built DAL.dll which is a class library containing an Entity Framework edmx.  In the Designer.cs, the following imported stored procedure is defined:

```
    <Function Name="Login_User" Aggregate="false" BuiltIn="false" NiladicFunction="false" IsComposable="false" ParameterTypeSemantics="AllowImplicitConversion" Schema="dbo">
      <Parameter Name="Login_Name" Type="nvarchar" Mode="In" />
      <Parameter Name="Password" Type="nvarchar" Mode="In" />
      <Parameter Name="SP_Return_Code" Type="int" Mode="InOut" />
    </Function>
```

Below I have used Reflection to find type1 as an ObjectContext type.  How do I discover the Login_User stored procedure by reflecting type1?

```
    private static void ReflectionTest()
    {
        var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\DAL.dll");

        // list stored procedure calls
        foreach (var type in asm.GetTypes())
        {
            if (type.BaseType == typeof(ObjectContext))
            {
                foreach (var type1 in type.GetMethods())
                {
                    // how do I reflect against type1 for its stored procedure names?
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using reflection for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First you will need to import your stored procedures as `Function` in your Entity model. Refer to this link for HowTo: http://ashishrocks.wordpress.com/2010/09/05/entity-framework-using-select-stored-procedures-for-entities-having-same-column-names/
2. At the time you are doing this, make sure you use some kind of naming convention for your `Function Import Name`. For example, prefix `SP_` to all your stored procedure function imports.
3. Once you add your SPs as functions in your Entity Model, you should be able to see them in your `Model.Designer.cs`. Compile updated DAL.

Now you can get your stored procedures like this:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\DAL.dll");

foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                                  where type.BaseType == typeof (ObjectContext)
                                  from methodInfo in type.GetMethods()
                                  where methodInfo.Name.StartsWith("SP_")
                                  select methodInfo)
{
    Console.WriteLine(methodInfo.Name);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```